# Can we save the notifications into SMS folder of iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsnotifications

I want to save the notifications, that come to my app from the server, in the SMS folder of an iPhone or iPad but I couldn't find a way about how to do. My app sends GET in a scheduled struct and if it realizes any changes I want to bring the notification and save it to the user's SMS folder. I parsed JSON during GET function and the changes which will trigger the saving method too are from JSON object... You can just give an idea about how to get started too.

PS: My app targets iOS 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to save messages that are sent via push directly into the user's SMS (messages) folder on the phone.

The short answer is you can't do this - your application is sandboxed, and unless you're running a jailbroken device where you have access to the required files it's not possible. How you're sending or what you're doing with the notification is irrelevant - the SMS app is out of bounds, and you won't be able to save anything to it using the public APIs.

Comment: How can i save the the notifications as message in somewhere else have you got any idea?

Comment: You can create an inbox in your app for your own notifications, of your own design. I think Urban Airship offer a bespoke product that allows you to have an inbox in-app for your push notifications.